# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getToken() on null

Tags: php, base-de-datos, php7

```
class Token {

    public $token;

    public function __construct(var_dump) {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    public function getToken() {
        return bin2hex(random_bytes(64)); //Generates new token when activating the plugin
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function () {

    $token = new Token();

    function validate() {
        $status = http_response_code();
        if($status == 200) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080/wordpress_pruebas/");
            header("Content-Type: application/json;");
            if ($token->getToken() == get_option('tokens_settings').[1]) {
                return new WP_REST_Response( array(
                    'message' => 'Access Successfully',
                    'version' => 1.0
                ),
                $status ); // Ok
            } else {
            return new WP_REST_Response( array(
                'message' => 'Access Failed',
                'version' => 1.0
            ),
            $status ); // Error
            }
        }
    }
    register_rest_route( 'authtoken', '/info', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'validate'
        )
    );
});
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el recorrido y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas Cómo preguntar y Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Creo que tienes problemas de ambitos de variables. $token no esta definido en la función si no fuera de ella y no es visible para ella.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$token` es invisible para tu función validate pues está definida fuera y no es accesible para ella.

Cambia tu validate por esto

```
    function validate() {
        $status = http_response_code();
        if($status == 200) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8080/wordpress_pruebas/");
            header("Content-Type: application/json;");
             $token = new Token();
            if ($token->getToken() == get_option('tokens_settings').[1]) {
                return new WP_REST_Response( array(
                    'message' => 'Access Successfully',
                    'version' => 1.0
                ),
                $status ); // Ok
            } else {
            return new WP_REST_Response( array(
                'message' => 'Access Failed',
                'version' => 1.0
            ),
            $status ); // Error
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Si, ahora me comprueba el token generado con la opción que he añadido a la base de datos.
Gracias JDev.

Comment: @EsKiva considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si te ha indicado el camino para resolver tu problema. Sólo hay que hacer clic en la flecha de cotejo color gris a la izquierda de la respuesta. También puedes votar a favor si no lo has hecho, marcando la flecha que apunta hacia arriba. Saludos.